# What is the shared library name of the current function

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I am working on a very big project. My project contains so many shared libraries. Some of the source files (CPP) are used in more than one shared libraries.

Just recently I come across a bug and needed to find out .so name of the function while it is in execution.

For example:

1. Test1.cpp contains function TestMethod()
2. Test1.cpp is included in lib1, lib2 and lib5. There are around 10 libraries.
3. So TestMethod is present in lib1, lib2 and lib5.
4. I want to call a function from inside TestMethod() such that while program is in execution, When TestMethod() is called, it should return whether it is lib1's version or lib2's version or lib5's version.

TestMethod() is creating an object of SubType which is subclass of SuperType. SubType and SuperType are defined in Test1.cpp. Sometimes lib6/lib7 are calling TestMethod and getting the object. After they are done, lib6/lib7 are calling delete on object pointer. But delete is crashing with segmentation fault with top of backtrace saying "typeinfo for class SubType".

[Note 1]: I am using libc++ library. And RTTI wont work across shared libraries. So I am suspecting this is leading to the issue. I am suspecting when delete is called, it(delete call in lib6) seems to be trying to get the typeinfo of SubType and failing to obtain it.

By having the information of what library is used, I can debug the compilation, linking flags used to prepare the shared library.

Would appreciate any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: That should depend on which library you actually link with, and *how* you link (are the libraries static or dynamic libraries?)

Comment: All of them dynamic libraries

Comment: Are your application being linked to *all* of the libraries? And also, does it really matter which of the definitions is used, as long as it does the same thing? What is the *real* problem you have? Please ask about that directly instead (unless this is just for curiosity, in which case you should explicitly state that, by editing your question).

Comment: Yes. My application is using all libraries. +Added more details.

Comment: Is it a bug in the `TestMethod` function itself? Or in some supporting functions it calls? Can you replicate the bug in a debug-build and running/stepping in a debugger? And unless you have different versions of the function in the different libraries, I still don't see how it matters if the bug is in that function. Fix the function once, rebuild all libraries, and it's fixed everywhere.

Comment: Added few more details in Note1;

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variable `LD_DEBUG=bindings` for this. E.g. to see where function `malloc` is defined:

```
$ LD_DEBUG=bindings ls 2>&1 | grep '\bmalloc\b'
45968:     binding file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] to ls [0]: normal symbol `malloc' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
45968:     binding file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 [0] to ls [0]: normal symbol `malloc' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
45968:     binding file /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `malloc' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
45968:     binding file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `malloc' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
45968:     binding file ls [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `malloc' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to get thing information programmatically. I have edited the description.